# Как сделать поиск по телефону в базе?

Tags: php, mysql

Требуется выполнять поиск по базе на совпадение телефона. **Как сделать правильный поиск по базе?** Ведь может быть телефон записан по разному: `+79033330033`, `89033330033`, `+7-(903)-333-00-33` или просто `9033330033` и т.д..

Comment: удаляйте все лишние символы при сохранении в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функция для php из моего проекта, которая возвращает номер из любого вида в вид 0991234567 (10 цифр, ведущий ноль - Украинский формат).
Все что ты ей дашь, хоть +380123456789, хоть 8-(0аааллл12)-_3456789, все равно будет в виде 0991234567. Поправь под себя, и в базу пиши все только в едином каком-то формате, с фиксированным количеством цифр. И крайне желательно чистить перед записью от всего что не цифры.

```
public function trimNumber($phone) //возвращает номер в едином формате
{
   $phone = trim($phone);
   $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone);
   $phone = substr($phone, -10);
   if (strlen($phone) == 7) {
   $phone = '044' . $phone; // если городской, добавить код Киева
   }
   return $phone;
}
```

А вот - функция, которая отображает потом эти номера из бд в едином понятном виде:

```
public function echoNumber($aphone) // номер в формате (xxx) xxx-xx-xx
{
   $sArea = substr($aphone, 0, 3);
   $sNumber1 = substr($aphone, 3, 3);
   $sNumber2 = substr($aphone, 6, 2);
   $sNumber3 = substr($aphone, 8, 2);
   $aphone = "(" . $sArea . ") " . $sNumber1 . "-" . $sNumber2 . "-" . $sNumber3;
   return ($aphone);
}
```

Comment: круто! Спасибо прям то что нужно! не ожидал даже что решение дадите.

Comment: Пользуйтесь! Я тоже столкнулся в свое время с этой проблемой, и наступал на кучу граблей пока решил.. Сейчас все отлично работает. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Все поступающие новые значения в базе надо очищать. Существующие чистить регулярками. Хранить только чистые. Показывать с маской.

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему, формат телефонных номеров в базе должен быть всего один. Тогда вам всего лишь нужно будет нормализовать номер перед поиском.

Что касается формата, то тут могут быть варианты. Неплохим вариантом является международный формат с ведущим плюсом (например `+71234567890`). Однако, в России существуют номера, звонки на которые можно сделать только во внутреннем формате, через ведущую восьмерку. Это все номера, начинающиеся с `8-800`.

Как следствие, я бы сначала рекомендовал вам привести в порядок вашу БД, а уже потом заниматься проблемами поиска.

Comment: На 8-800 можно позвонить и через +7-800 ... просто все привыкли называть его 8-800